# Laravel post request not works

Tags: laravel

I have Form in Laravel and when i submit the form to redirect another page("action = panel") with inputs's value. but problem is that when i enter in another's link it displays error. what is wrong?

This is form

[image]

[this is another page when submit form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryOtJ.png)

[this is error when i enter in link again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIwCc.png)

this is form code:

```
<form action="{{route('adminPanel')}}" class="form" method="POST">
    <p>Name:</p>
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <p>Password:</p>
    <input type="password" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter As Admin" class="submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

this is routes:

```
Route::get('/', [

    'uses' => 'AdminController@getAdminIndex',

    'as' => 'index.admin'
]);
Route::post('/panel', [
    'uses' => 'AdminController@getAdminPanel',
    'as' => 'adminPanel'

]);
```

this is controller:

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function getAdminIndex(){
        return view('admin/index');
    }
    public function getAdminPanel(Request $request){
        return view('admin/admin', ['name' => $request->name]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use the following statement in form as {{ csrf_field() }}

Comment: Do you insert into database when you submit the form?

Comment: Try adding `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` inside your head tag and use `{{ csrf_field() }}` inside your form

Comment: not works. it must be instead of csrf_token() ?

Comment: Your are going to save it on a DB or just show in `panel` page?

Comment: just panel page

Comment: Your code looks fine and the error you get when you hit enter is normal cuz its a post request on that route. But can you post admin/admin view code plz and maybe try to `dd($request->all())`

Comment: You should stick with default auth.

Answer (score 1):

this is because when you enter an address in address bar, your are actually sending a `get` request. but you've defined your route with `post` method!
to fix this you can use `any`:

```
Route::any('/panel', [
    'uses' => 'AdminController@getAdminPanel',
    'as' => 'adminPanel'

]);
```

and in controller:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function getAdminIndex(){
        return view('admin/index');
    }
    public function getAdminPanel(Request $request){
       $name = $request->name ?: Auth::user()->name; 
       return view('admin/admin', ['name' => $name]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what namespace is for Auth::user() ??

Comment: @GenoMumladze use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth' not found

Comment: i want to save input's value when i enter in adress bar again

Comment: @GenoMumladze localhost:8080/myblog/public/admin/panel?name=Geno

Comment: i can understand

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following statement in form as {{ csrf_field() }}

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes routes may create you an issue. Try below snippet.

```
<form action="{{route('adminPanel')}}" class="form" method="POST">
  <p>Name:</p>
  <input type="text" name="name"><br>

  <p>Password:</p>
  <input type="password" name="password"><br>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter As Admin" class="submit">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

Correct your Routes as below and try.

```
Route::post('/adminPanel', ['uses' => 'AdminController@getAdminPanel', 'as' => 'adminPanel' ]);
```

Comment: Can you try this change in ur controller. public function getAdminPanel(Request $request){
        print_r($request->all();
    }

Comment: i want to save input's value when i enter in adress bar again

Comment: Yes, you can do that but is that allowing to print data using above function?

Comment: Are you able to print the data?

Comment: i add in controller but displays some problem